# Why does the Firebase notification not receive when the program is foreground and only works background?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Why does the Firebase notification not receive when the program is foreground and only receive notification when the program is running in the background.

My code is

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
```

Comment: Please specifi what do you mena by "fail"

Comment: edited mu question

Comment: `onMessageReceived` is not called?

Comment: onMessageReceived only called when the my app is background and not work in Foreground

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml file.Your service defination should be like this

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>

 </service>
```

If `intent-filter` is not added your app won't receive notification when in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Modify code: When the application is in foreground you will get notification not data so get the data as getNotification().getTitle() and other things needed

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  //System.currentTimeMillis is unique ID
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) 
  System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,0);
     NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompact.Builder(this) 
                   .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
```

Intent and PendingIntent is used to open the Activity when clicked Notification

Notification Builder to set the title and body of the Notification shown

NotificationManager is used to create notification.